# Roof patch, how long will it last?

Tags: roof, roofing

We've had this since we bought the house. Underneath in the attic it looks as if part of that roof collapsed (probably a foot went throught). Then someone patched it up in a crappy way.

I have no leaks but I wonder how urgent is the repair of this and how much will it cost? I could also attempt to DIY but not sure how many shingles will have to be removed to fix this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you plan to sort that within 2 or 3 years, one reason being that those joint lines should not line up...